# Importing web3 causing a problem in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ethereum, web3js

```
Compiled with problems:
```

ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Blockchain\lottery-React\node_modules\cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 9:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Blockchain\lottery-React\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/account.js 71:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in 'C:\Blockchain\lottery-React\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
- install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/address.js 14:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in 'C:\Blockchain\lottery-React\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
- install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/object.js 46:31-48

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in 'C:\Blockchain\lottery-React\node_modules\ethereumjs-util\dist.browser'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "assert": require.resolve("assert/") }'
- install 'assert'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "assert": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js 31:74-91

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Blockchain\lottery-React\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js 7:193-227

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'C:\Blockchain\lottery-React\node_modules\web3-eth-accounts\node_modules\eth-lib\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 30:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Blockchain\lottery-React\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
- install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "http": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js 32:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Blockchain\lottery-React\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
- install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "https": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 37:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Blockchain\lottery-React\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
- install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "http": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 39:12-28

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Blockchain\lottery-React\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
- install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "https": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js 41:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Blockchain\lottery-React\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
- install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "os": false }

ERROR

src\App.js
Line 4:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: here is the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70559396/webpack-breaking-change/70560145#70560145

Comment: Another solution is to downgrade `react-cripts` from `5.0.0` to `4.0.3`

Answer (score 6):

Hi I was just working through this issue as well.

Turned out this was more of a situation involving a transition from webpack4 to 5.  One needs to manually add the [webpack node polyfill](https://github.com/Richienb/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin)

In my situation
`npm install react-app-rewired --save` [exposes webpack config](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired)
`npm install npm install node-polyfill-webpack-plugin --save`

in `config-overrides.js` in root

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.plugins.push(new NodePolyfillPlugin({
    excludeAliases: ["console"]
  }))
  return config
}
```

Comment: I added this to my webpack.config.js under plugins and worked a charm.